# Change Woocommerce My Account Tab name depending on User Role

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I am building a ecommerce with Woocommerce, and I would like to change My Account Tabs name depending on User role (some user roles have access to several products and some just one product so I need to implement plural/singular variations for the tab name). Is there a function to achieve this ? I've found some snippets that create more or less similar actions but can't find out how to make it work "my way".

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the woocommerce filter `woocommerce_account_menu_items` and checking current user role.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'rename_my_account_tabs', 9999 );
 
function rename_my_account_tabs( $items ) {

  if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = (array) $user->roles;

    if(in_array('administrator',$roles)){
      $items = array(
         'dashboard'       => __( 'Dashboard Admin', 'woocommerce' ),
         'orders'          => __( 'Orders Admin', 'woocommerce' ),
         'downloads'       => __( 'Downloads Admin', 'woocommerce' ),
         'edit-address'    => _n( 'Addresses Admin', 'Address', (int) wc_shipping_enabled(), 'woocommerce' ),
         'payment-methods' => __( 'Payment methods Admin', 'woocommerce' ),
         'edit-account'    => __( 'Account details', 'woocommerce' ),
         'customer-logout' => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
      );
    }elseif(in_array('suscriber',$roles)){
      $items = array(
         'dashboard'       => __( 'Dashboard Admin', 'woocommerce' ),
         'orders'          => __( 'Orders Admin', 'woocommerce' ),
         'downloads'       => __( 'Downloads Admin', 'woocommerce' ),
         'edit-address'    => _n( 'Addresses Admin', 'Address', (int) wc_shipping_enabled(), 'woocommerce' ),
         'payment-methods' => __( 'Payment methods Admin', 'woocommerce' ),
         'edit-account'    => __( 'Account details', 'woocommerce' ),
         'customer-logout' => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
      );
      }
  }

   return $items;
}
```